# Using sequences of images for as an input for time distributed conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm currently attempting to build a model that uses image sequences and classifies each item in the sequence (not retaining state between sequences) in Keras with a TF backend; however, I'm running into an issue with the input shape for the first layer.

the model looks like this:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'), input_shape=(10, 1, 224, 224, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(1, 1))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.5))

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I think my issue comes from a lack of understanding regarding array shapes, and I'm most likely making an amateur mistake here. Each individual sequence gets loaded into a numpy array of shape (10, 1, 224, 224, 3) where the first axis is the number of items in the sequence(they are padded to be the same length), the second is the batch size, and the others are simply an RGB image. In my understanding from reading the available information on the docs (and my errors) a conv2D inside the time distributed wrapper takes a 5D array, essentially being formatted as the normal conv2D input of (batch size, rows, cols, channels) plus an added dimension for time (each item in the sequence). Is this anywhere close to accurate?

Moving on to the issue I'm facing... 
If I try to input an image sequence of shape (10, 1, 224, 224, 3), I get the error 
"ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 224 != 3". Can anyone shed some light on this? I'm fairly certain I'm not shaping the input array and the input_shape properly.

Another question I have that someone might be able to answer is: 
Once this is resolved and I can use the sequence as an input, how do I go about feeding the model not just a single image sequence like shown above, but instead use an array of sequences? My dataset is made up of thousands of these sequences. All my previous experience in this stuff has been using Caffe and certainly not anything using recurrent models so not only am I unfamiliar with actually implementing recurrent networks, I am unfamiliar with Keras overall (although I'm beginning to learn, albeit slowly lol). From my experience and observations, Caffe provides a heavy layer of abstraction between you and the data inputs so I've never had to deal with this before.

I hope this question and my problem is clear and concise, and any information provided is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Keras documentation, you have to update the input_dim to be

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'), input_shape=(10, 224, 224, 3)))
```

and then use an image generator that fits the new shape of data.
you can use the tweaked one in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Emadeldeen24/736c33ac2af0c00cc48810ad62e1f54a).

It's the same as the main Keras ImageDataGenerator but I added an option to take more than one image/frame on each iteration. This is by changing the parameter **frames_per_step** to specify the number of frames/images you want to include in each iteration.

This is how to use it:

```
from tweaked_ImageGenerator_v2 import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_data=datagen.flow_from_directory('path/to/data', target_size=(x, y), batch_size=32, frames_per_step=4)
```

Comment: Is this just the same as ImageDataGenerator(), but for image sequences? such that using images for CNN+LSTM? What about unbalanced frames as sequences for the video class (images)

Comment: yes, the same but added that feature for image sequences. What do you mean by unbalanced frames?

Comment: What I mean by unbalanced frames, some videos have more frames such as video1 of classA has 200 frames, while video2 of classA has 40 frames. Because I guess frames_per_step is the amount of the frames that are taken from each video for each step?